# Google chrome not opening in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 on a Ryzen 5 CPU machine, I install Chrome from https://www.google.co.uk/chrome/ choosing the 64bit `.deb` package, and the install works with no errors seen.

However running Chrome it never displays anything, and give an error:

```
kevin@home:~$ google-chrome libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)

[23127:23127:0422/093510.765043:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

I tried `rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome`, I also tried `google-chrome --disable-gpu --no-sandbox`, but both don't work.

This is the Chrome version:

```
kevin@home:~$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 100.0.4896.127
```

That was the way out `sudo google-chrome --disable-gpu --no-sandbox`:

```
kevin@home:~$ sudo google-chrome --disable-gpu --no-sandbox
[sudo] password for kevin: 
[29946:29973:0422/095302.474445:ERROR:bus.cc(397)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[29946:29973:0422/095302.474504:ERROR:bus.cc(397)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
[29981:29981:0422/095302.480831:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] DisplayVkXcb.cpp:59 (initialize): xcb_connect() failed, error 1
[29981:29981:0422/095302.480902:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:966 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Not initialized.
[29981:29981:0422/095302.480949:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(808)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Not initialized.
[29981:29981:0422/095302.480973:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1430)] eglInitialize SwANGLE failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[29981:29981:0422/095302.481006:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(20)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[29981:29981:0422/095302.481880:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(188)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[29946:29973:0422/095302.483125:ERROR:bus.cc(397)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[29946:29973:0422/095302.483146:ERROR:bus.cc(397)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
[30017:30017:0422/095302.509279:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] DisplayVkXcb.cpp:59 (initialize): xcb_connect() failed, error 1
[30017:30017:0422/095302.509350:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:966 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Not initialized.
[30017:30017:0422/095302.509401:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(808)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Not initialized.
[30017:30017:0422/095302.509432:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1430)] eglInitialize SwANGLE failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[30017:30017:0422/095302.509467:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(20)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[30017:30017:0422/095302.510423:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(188)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
[30043:30043:0422/095302.523272:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] DisplayVkXcb.cpp:59 (initialize): xcb_connect() failed, error 1
[30043:30043:0422/095302.523368:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:966 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Not initialized.
[30043:30043:0422/095302.523423:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(808)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Not initialized.
[30043:30043:0422/095302.523468:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1430)] eglInitialize SwANGLE failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[30043:30043:0422/095302.523512:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(20)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[30043:30043:0422/095302.524597:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(188)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
[30094:30094:0422/095302.533872:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(446)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is 
[30094:30107:0422/095302.535111:ERROR:x11_software_bitmap_presenter.cc(141)] XGetWindowAttributes failed for window 10485763
```

Running as `root` I get a bit further, but it hangs with a small (and empty) "Welcome to Google Chrome", box and lots of errors, any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Experienced the same `google-chrome libva error` on an Intel when downloading both Chrome and Opera (chromium based) for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Resolved the issue for both browsers by restarting after completing the download (entering `reboot` into the terminal).

Although, I feel silly suggesting to turn your computer off and on again.

Comment: I did try a few reboots and no change.  I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu and not selecting the option that talks about downloading 3rd party drivers - and it works fine.

Comment: `reboot` worked for me after a fresh install of Ubuntu 22 and downloading from Google's website.

Comment: Same problem with apt install :
 * apt remove google-chrome-stable
 * download .deb on Google official website
 * dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
And it's work... May be old version on apt...

Comment: Rebooting worked for me, too.

Answer (score 3):

I found this article: https://notes.enovision.net/linux/google-chrome-not-starting-in-ubuntu and it helped.

Basically, what I did:

```
sudo vim /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

Change:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
```

To:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --password-store=basic %U
```

Also removing local config files seems to help:

```
rm ~/.config/google-chrome/ -rf
```

Comment: Worked for me. It was failing with an error about kwallet before. The weird thing is that passing the flag once was enough. Not needed thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Same overall problem but in my case it was a file permissions obstruction:

```
$ sudo apt install wget
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
wget is already the newest version (1.21.2-2ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
--2023-03-26 14:35:18--  https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 172.253.116.91, 172.253.116.93, 172.253.116.190, ...
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|172.253.116.91|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 93863468 (90M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb’

google-chrome-stabl 100%[===================>]  89.51M  4.97MB/s    in 19s     

2023-03-26 14:35:38 (4.66 MB/s) - ‘google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb’ saved [93863468/93863468]

$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 338595 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (111.0.5563.110-1) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (111.0.5563.110-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/google-chrome (google-chrome) in auto mode
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.6+22.04.20220217-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47ubuntu4) ...
$ google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 8: /usr/bin/readlink: Permission denied
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 10: /usr/bin/dirname: Permission denied
/usr/bin/google-chrome: line 24: /usr/bin/mkdir: Permission denied
```

The 3 folders:

/usr/bin/readlink
/usr/bin/dirname
/usr/bin/mkdir

are readable and executable by all users but only writable by root.

Is there code in /usr/bin/google-chrome that is trying to alter the code in these 3 directories ?

It is really strange why Chrome has always seemed to have a problem with Ubuntu . . .

I think we should take this clanger of a hint here.

Let's all stick to Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04 has issues with Wayland.

Solution: (worked for me)

- Use X11
- Try removing any conflicting applications, in my case culprit was Citrix Receiver.

Remove with follwing command:

`sudo apt remove icaclient && sudo apt purge icaclient`

I hope it works for you as well.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1464995/1690831

Comment: Not an answer. Thousands if not 10 s of thousand run Chrome under Wayland.

Comment: Here it is a Graphics Card driver related issue, other must have working Graphics card driver support, in my case it is a Dell OEM Laptop, and Intel Iris Xe Graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on a new machine:

ubuntu 22.04.02 lts
chrome Version 113.0.5672.63 (Official Build) (64-bit)
AMD Ryzen 9 6900HX with Radeon Graphics.

google-chrome-stable starts but just with blank page, cannot open anything.

bash error:

```
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[17085:17085:0508/101428.353088:ERROR:service_worker_task_queue.cc(234)] DidStartWorkerFail lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf: 14
```

It does work using the --no-sandbox option, but that feels unsafe.

Any more ideas? :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent confirmed bug here that appears to have the same error message that I'm encountering, and seems to be similar to what was reported in this thread:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-nvidia-5.19/+bug/2017980

I think this means Ubuntu and nvidia are working on it.