# Chrome and Vivaldi won't work at Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, google-chrome, 22.04, vivaldi

After a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04, and a few days in using the OS, suddenly Chrome and Vivaldi stop functioning.

In the case of Chrome, the start page is buffering and eventually returning a "page is unresponsive message".

In the case of Vivaldi, I can only see a blank page with its logo.

I've tried removing and reinstalling again, as also as disabling extensions and GPU in Vivaldi, but nothing changes.

Brave browser works well, so I assume that there is a bug lying with chromium-based browsers.

I am looking forward to your help!

Comment: How did you install Chrome? Could you try this? (it can be installed alongside any other Chrome installation): https://snapcraft.io/chromium

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply! Yes I did also install chromium as a snap package to test if it could work, and unfortunately it didn't. Also uninstalling and reinstalling did not do the trick either.

Comment: @Noowada if you are using wayland, try switching to x11

Comment: echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE returns x11, so already there and still the browsers are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that worked for me was starting Vivaldi in the terminal with `vivaldi-stable --no-sandbox` (as stated in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403694/google-chrome-not-opening-in-ubuntu-22-04-lts?rq=1)). Although I haven't tested it extensively, and also haven't tested this with Chrome, I can confirm that browsing in Vivaldi works just fine now. I hope this works for you too.

**Edit**: to make it stick, you can edit the vivaldi-stable.desktop file in /usr/share/applications. To do so:

Open a terminal, navigate to the directory, enter `sudo cp vivaldi-stable.desktop vivaldi-stable.desktop_backup` (to make a backup - just in case something goes wrong), then enter `sudo gedit vivaldi-stable.desktop`. Once opened, look for the line starting with "Exec". It should look like this:

> Exec=/usr/bin/vivaldi-stable %U

Change it to:

> Exec=/usr/bin/vivaldi-stable --no-sandbox %U

Now you should be able to start Vivaldi, add it to your favourites (so the icon is always visible on the launcher) and open it from there the next time. It will save you the hassle of launching from the terminal.

There is also the option to change the Exec line in the section "[Desktop Action new-private-window]", but that is up to you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick for vivaldi for the time being!